# Active constraints in UITableViewCell don't get updated when updated from cellForRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

I have a view with two leading constraints that conflict each other. One with leading offset, other without. The 'constant' property works for active constraint. But I want to enable/disable constraints to fit my needs. It works in every place except `UITableViewCell`, when called from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.
Here is my cell:

```
class WowCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var leading: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var leadingSpace: NSLayoutConstraint!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func setup(ye:Bool) {
        setActiveConstraint(ye: ye)

        //doesn't help
        setNeedsLayout()
        layoutIfNeeded()
        needsUpdateConstraints()
        setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        needsUpdateConstraints()
        setNeedsLayout()
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    func setActiveConstraint(ye:Bool){
        leading.isActive = !ye
        leadingSpace.isActive = ye
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        //when called from here, it does work
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Edit: As Prashant Tukadiya advised, it works by changing priorities of both active constraints. But be aware that both constraint have to be [lower than 1000](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31186261/2528850).

```
func setActiveConstraint(ye:Bool){
    leading.priority  = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: !ye ? 999 : 250)
    leadingSpace.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: ye ? 999 : 250)
}
```

Comment: Why don't you change the constant value directly  by maintaining single constraint rather than two

Comment: @Prashant Tukadiya Because it's not always convenient to compute the constant. This code is just a simplified example.

Comment: what do you mean by not  convenient to compute the constant ? Could you pl. add some more info that what you exactly required . there might be other solution

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya for me changing priorities to activate/deactivate constraint is a workaround comparing to direct activation/deactivation

Comment: @derpoliuk That what I have posted as answer

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya yes, it looks like workaround for me. I posted the answer where it's possible to directly change `isActive` property to activate/deactivate layout constraint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with priority  as active / deactivate constraint call `addConstraint` and `removeConstraint`  internally

```
func setActiveConstraint(ye:Bool){
    leading.priority  = !ye ? 999 : 250
    leading.priority = ye ? 999 : 250
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you deactive your constraint it will be release by ARC because it's weak property in your vc.
You can change by removing weak to handle this.

```
@IBOutlet var leading: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var leadingSpace: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

But you need the release them right after they aren't needed if you don't want a memory leak

Comment: You are correct about releasing. But it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to do that without changing priorities:

1. Override `updateConstraints()` in your `UITableViewCell`
2. Activate/deactivate constraint there
3. Make sure to call `super.updateConstraints()` at the end