# Is it possible to change the Y-position of action sheet styled UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, swift

Current, I am showing action sheet style `UIAlertController` via the following code

```
@IBAction func attachmentButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let chooseImageImage = UIImage(systemName: "photo")
    let takePhotoImage = UIImage(systemName: "camera")
    let drawingImage = UIImage(systemName: "paintbrush.pointed")
    let recordingImage = UIImage(systemName: "mic")

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let chooseImageAction = UIAlertAction(title: "choose_image".localized, style: .default) {
        UIAlertAction in
        // Write your code here
    }
    chooseImageAction.setValue(chooseImageImage, forKey: "image")

    let takePhotoAction = UIAlertAction(title: "take_photo".localized, style: .default) {
        UIAlertAction in
        // Write your code here
    }
    takePhotoAction.setValue(takePhotoImage, forKey: "image")

    let drawingAction = UIAlertAction(title: "drawing".localized, style: .default) {
        UIAlertAction in
        // Write your code here
    }
    drawingAction.setValue(drawingImage, forKey: "image")

    let recordingAction = UIAlertAction(title: "recording".localized, style: .default) {
        UIAlertAction in
        // Write your code here
    }
    recordingAction.setValue(recordingImage, forKey: "image")

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel".systemLocalized, style: .cancel) {
        UIAlertAction in
        // It will dismiss action sheet
    }

    alert.addAction(chooseImageAction)
    alert.addAction(takePhotoAction)
    alert.addAction(drawingAction)
    alert.addAction(recordingAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55653187/swift-default-alertviewcontroller-breaking-constraints
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The outcome is as following

[image]

---

I was wondering, is there a way to adjust the Y-position of `UIAlertController`, so that it will not block the bottom toolbar visibility? I wish the achieve the effect as shown in the following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: You can’t customize a UIAlertController. Just write your own presented view controller and place it where you like.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the subview and then change the constant of the bottom constraint.

```
\\-----OtherCode-----

if let bottomConstraint = alert.view.subviews[0].subviews.last?.constraints.first(where: { ($0.firstAttribute == .bottom) }) {
    bottomConstraint.constant = bottomConstraint.constant - 50
}
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```